# How does Rails / Devise relate a session to a user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm tinkering with Devise in Rails and storing sessions in MySQL (using the directive `MyApp::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store` in `config/initializers/session_store.rb`)

In my sessions table, I've got a session with a `session_id` and `data`, both of which are unintelligible.

The `session_id` is more or less random, [as explained here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-id). I'm not sure what's in the data, since this is a dummy app for now; the only data to know about this user is that it is signed in.

What I'm trying to understand is: **How does Rails or Devise relate this session to a user?** There's no `user_id` column on a session (I assume for good reason).

Answer (score 1):

Look in the request headers for a cookie matching your session_id.

Comment: Yes, my request header contains a cookie which contains my session_id, so it can look up the correct row in the sessions table. But how does it go from there to "...and therefore this is user1@example.com"? In other words, how does it know which user that session belongs to?

Comment: My sessions contain "warden.user.user.key" which refers to the User and ID of the current user.